# Python - Load all images from Directory for facial recognition

Tags: python

```
images = "./img/known/*.jpg"

#Add known images 
image_of_person = face_recognition.load_image_file(images)
person_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image_of_person)[0]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: './img/known/*.jpg'
```

Is there anyway I can take all .jpg items in the folder "Known" and then use that as the 'Face to look for'?

For example if a folder has 5 .jpg files of faces, can I take all 5 images and have the code search all faces?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
for x in os.listdir(path):
```

And if you have other files in the directory than jpg use

```
if x.split(".jpg"):
#something
```

Comment: With the diretory how would you then place that into the facial recognition?                       Ie, #Add known images 
image_of_person = face_recognition.load_image_file(filename)
person_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image_of_person)[0]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a for loop to achieve this. I have shown an example using Pillow library

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
image_list = []
for Imagename in glob.glob('yourpath/*.jpg'):
    im=Image.open(Imagename)
    image_list.append(im)
```

Comment: Gave that a go earlier. I still get the "'list' object has no attribute 'read'" error.

Comment: this may be due to some non ascii characters in the name
try this:
Imagename.encode('ascii','ignore').decode()